# Match the similar 7 digit numbers where the first 5 digits are the same but the last two are not?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two different excel columns. One from Project A and one from Project B.

In both project A and Project B there are numbers that are similar, the first five digits are the same but the last two digits differ.

For Example the number in 
Project A is **54321**34, **54322**63, and so on. But for Project B they are
Project B is **54321**74, **54322**72, and so on.

I would like two fill Column D so that the corresponding Project A number matches.

Example of formula
[image]

In the picture provided I highlighted the number in red, of what I would like Excel to find. In cell D3 I would like Excel to place 5432134.

I tried using `vlookup` and cutting the last two digits out as shown in the image but that did not work

Any idea of a formula that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one match, then you can use SUMIFS and ROUNDDOWN.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,B:B,">="&ROUNDDOWN(F3,-2),B:B,"<"&ROUNDDOWN(F3,-2)+100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
D3: =INDEX(Project_A,MAX((INT(F3/100)=INT(Project_A/100))*ROW(Project_A))-2)
```

and fill down.

The `-2` is to compensate for the fact that the data starts in row 3 and not in row 1. So adjust accordingly if your table starts in a different row.

[image]